# jq read .txt file and write the values to json file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to use `jq` to parse a `.txt` file with a list of country codes and write them to the value in a JSON object.

Here is what I have so far:

```
cat myfile.json | 
jq -R -f test_id.txt 'select(.country == []).country = "test_id.txt"' > newfile.json
```

Where `.txt` file looks like this:

```
"NSC"
"KZC"
"KCC"
"KZL"
"NZG"
"VRU"
"ESM"
"KZF"
"SFU"
"EWF"
"KQY"
"KQV"
```

and my JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "scsRequestId": null,
  "includeMetadata": true,
  "includeHoldings": true,
  "country": [],
  "region": [],
  "oclcSymbol": []
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected QQSTRING_START, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 2:
"KZC"
jq: 1 compile error
```

I want the list of country codes to go into the country array.

Comment: Is there a reason you have the quotes in your input text file? If it's not a JSON string, why quote as if it were?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's the way I get it.  Not by choice.  I have tried testing a similar file without quotes but that won't work either.  I could remove the quotes before processing with jq.

Comment: I notice that your edit is more recent than my answer. Is that to say that the answer was predicated on a misreading of the question? [When I run it, the list *does* go in the country array; the variable being misnamed "regions" in the initial code revision is meaningless, since it doesn't impact the output].

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Can you please add to the question what the expected output would look like?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`-f`'s argument is the file to read the filter to run from. If you want to read data from a file, that's a use for `--slurpfile`, not `-f`.

Thus:

```
jq --slurpfile countries test_id.txt '.country=$countries' <myfile.json >newfile.json
```

---

When run with your provided inputs, the resulting contents in `newfile.json` are:

```
{
  "scsRequestId": null,
  "includeMetadata": true,
  "includeHoldings": true,
  "country": [
    "NSC",
    "KZC",
    "KCC",
    "KZL",
    "NZG",
    "VRU",
    "ESM",
    "KZF",
    "SFU",
    "EWF",
    "KQY",
    "KQV"
  ],
  "region": [],
  "oclcSymbol": []
}
```