# How to check for presence of 'key' in jq before iterating over the values

Tags: json, bash, jq

I get `Cannot iterate over null (null)` from the below query because `.property_history` is not present in `result` object.

How do I check for the presence of `.property_history` key before proceeding with `map(...)`?

I tried using something like

```
sold_year= `echo "$content" | jq 'if has("property_history") then 
map(select(.event_name == "Sold"))[0].date' else null end
```

**Original Query:**

```
sold_year=`echo "$content" | jq '.result.property_history | map(select(.event_name == "Sold"))[0].date'`
```

**JSON:**

```
{
    "result":{
        "property_history":[
            {
                "date":"01/27/2016",
                "price_changed":0,
                "price":899750,
                "event_name":"Listed",
                "sqft":0
            },
            {
                "date":"12/15/2015",
                "price_changed":0,
                "price":899750,
                "event_name":"Listed",
                "sqft":2357
            },
            {
                "date":"08/30/2004",
                "price_changed":0,
                "price":739000,
                "event_name":"Sold",
                "sqft":2357
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use the [select-expression](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) in `jq` to do what you intend to achieve, something as,

```
jq '.result 
  | select(.property_history != null) 
  | .property_history 
  | map(select(.event_name == "Sold"))[0].date'
```

Comment: select(.property_history != null) is redundant, you can write it as simply: select(.property_history)

Comment: @icenac - The two expressions are not equivalent. Beware!

Comment: @peak I know, but for this particular example they are

Comment: @icenac "special cases are not special enough to break the rules"

Answer (score 40):

Technically, to test for the presence of a property, you should use `has/1`, but in the present context, it would probably be better to use the postfix `?` operator, e.g.:

```
$ jq '.result 
  | .property_history[]?
  | select(.event_name == "Sold") 
  | .date'
"08/30/2004"
```

If there is a possibility that the value of .result is not a JSON object, then you could replace the second line above by:

```
try(.property_history[])
```

Comment: cool. i tried that... but it was giving `boolean`. Looks like trick is `.[]`

Comment: You may shorten this to `jq '.result.property_history[]? | select(.event_name == "Sold") | .date'`

Comment: This is far more compact, than the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer results in error when `property_history` does not exist. The shortened version in the comment by Olaf does work.

Answer (score 36):

use `has("mykey1")` (for objects) or `has(0)` (for arrays):

```
jq 'has("name")' <<< '{"name": "hello"}'
```

output:

```
true
```

Comment: `if [ "$( jq 'has("alert")' <<< $this_alert_json )" == "true" ]; then`

Comment: for POSIX shells (no redirection feature): 
`echo "{\"name\": \"hello\"}" | jq 'has("name")'`

Comment: if you aren't sure the incoming string is valid JSON: `echo "{\"name\": \"hello\"}" | jq -R 'fromjson? | has("name")'` this will not throw an error for bad JSON, if that's what you want

Comment: Can I give the json file here ????

Comment: @Srinivasu https://stackoverflow.com/a/36273303/5563327

Answer (score 6):

General pattern:

```
try (...) // "default_value"
```

With your logic:

```
jq 'try (.result.property_history | map(select(.event_name == "Sold"))[0].date) // "default_value"'
```

`try` (without a catch) returns empty if the expression fails. `//` provides a default value if the value is empty.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I hadn't seen the `try` feature and I find this easily the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use [//](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://) together with [empty](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#empty):

```
jq '.result.property_history // empty | map(select(.event_name == "Sold"))[0:1][].date'
```

Another alternative is to use an additional select:

```js
jq '.result.property_history | select(.) | map(select(.event_name == "Sold"))[0:1][].date'
```

Answer (score 5):

The shortest you can use (with the bonus that the **exit code will be set**):

```bash
# Example that exits with code 0
jq -e 'has("result")'

# Example that exists with code 0
jq -e '.result[].property_history | has("price")'

# Example that exists with code 1
jq -e '.result[].property_history | has("dummyKey")'
```

In these examples, because of setting the flag `-e`, if `has` returned true, the exit code will be set to 0, otherwise 1. Which saves unnecessary additional steps.