# How to yq select contains on a field with an object with a value of tags and special characters?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, jq, yq

I need to add ManagedPolicyArns to many IAM roles in many cloudformation.yaml files. Some already have this policy added so I need to select, in order to add, only those that do not. I'm using yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.27.3, which is fantastic.

Command:

```
yq --from-file add_policy.yq cloudformation.yaml
```

`cloudformation.yaml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  MyPrefix:
    Description: MyPrefix
    Type: String
Resources:
  MyRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
              - sts:TagSession
      Path: /
```

Partially working in that it always adds the policy creating duplicates, `add_policy.yq`:

```
( .Resources[] |= 
    select(
        (.Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service.[] == "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" 
            or .Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service.[] == "lambda.amazonaws.com")
        and (.Properties.ManagedPolicyArns | contains([{"Fn::ImportValue": "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn"}]) | not ) )
    .Properties.ManagedPolicyArns += {"Fn::ImportValue": "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn" | . tag = "!Sub" }
)
```

Does does not add the policy at all and fails silently, `add_policy.yq`

```
( .Resources[] |= 
    select(
        (.Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service.[] == "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" 
            or .Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service.[] == "lambda.amazonaws.com")
        and (.Properties.ManagedPolicyArns[]."Fn::ImportValue" | contains("${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn" | . tag = "!Sub") | not) )
    .Properties.ManagedPolicyArns += {"Fn::ImportValue": "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn" | . tag = "!Sub" }
)
```

I'm failing to see from the simpler examples in the docs, How do I keep `ManagedPolicyArns` unique and not add the new entry to it if it already exists?

Comment: Whoops, thanks @Inian, I've added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097410/how-to-check-for-presence-of-key-in-jq-before-iterating-over-the-values" and also trying out some various queries to see what output .Resources.Properties.ManagedPolicyArns[] is returning (ie. nulls), I figured it out.

There's a list of null values that it is iterating and that causes the expression to just break and not evaluate. I need to instead return true for items that are null or not matching, then all will be handled and the expression evaluated fully to true or false.

`add_policy.yq`:

```
( .Resources[] |= 
    select(
        (.Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service.[] == "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" 
            or .Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Service.[] == "lambda.amazonaws.com")
        and (
            .Properties.ManagedPolicyArns[] == null
            or ( .Properties.ManagedPolicyArns[]."Fn::ImportValue" == "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn" | not )
        )
    )
    .Properties.ManagedPolicyArns += {"Fn::ImportValue": "${MyPrefix}-my-policy-arn" | . tag = "!Sub" }
)
```